# Facebook's open graph action submission rejected

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

My app has four open graph actions, which I want to publish on behalf of user. I submitted the app for review two times, but each time facebook replies with,

*Your app isn't loading properly and errors appear while testing the app.*

I have provided a test user to login to my app. At my place, I can load my app without any problem and login to this test user's account and also publish actions properly. I don't know why facebook is having this problem. How can I get more details about, how the app is not loading properly and what errors are appearing while testing?

Comment: Try accessing your app from somewhere else.

Comment: Yes, I can load my app properly with the test account provided to Facebook, from other places too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, it was some error on Facebook's side itself. They approved the app in third submission.